# Format number based on pattern

Tags: kotlin

- I need to format numbers based on pattern given in the code.
- Number : `12038902.9`, Pattern : `"##,###,###.##"`. Output must be like : `12,038,902.9` I have to use this `"##,###,###.##"` & `"##.###.###,##"` also.

I have tried this but not working :

```
fun main() {
        val number = 12038902.90
        val pattern = "##,###,###.##"
        val formattedNumber = formatNumber(number, pattern)
        println(formattedNumber)
    }
    
    fun formatNumber(number: Double, pattern: String): String {
         val parts = pattern.split(".")
        val integerPart = parts[0].replace(",", "")
        val decimalPartFormat = parts[1]
    
        val intPartFormat = "%d"
        val decimalPartForm = "%.${decimalPartFormat.length}f"
    
        val formattedIntPart = String.format(intPartFormat, number.toInt()).replaceFirst("(?<=\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))".toRegex(), ",")
        val decimalPart = (number * 10.0.pow(decimalPartFormat.length)).toInt() % 10.0.pow(decimalPartFormat.length).toInt()
        val formattedDecimalPart = String.format("%0${decimalPartFormat.length}d", decimalPart).replaceFirst("0*$".toRegex(), "").replaceFirst("(?<=\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))".toRegex(), ",")
    
        return "$formattedIntPart.$formattedDecimalPart"
    }
```

Getting this output : `12,038902.9` which is wrong I want is `12,038,902.9`:

**Pattern & number both are dynamic so I need to adjust as per it's need.**

Comment: What is the desired behaviour if the number doesn't match the pattern? For instance, what should be the output if the pattern is `##.##` and number is `9` or `999.999`?

Comment: Very good question! I think we have to adjust numbers based on hash
for 9 -> 9.00
for 999.999 -> 1000.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe u can use DecimalFormat for this purpose. It takes care of grouping, proper separators etc.
Result for your the input `12038902.9` is: `12,038,902.9`

```
fun convert(number: String) {
    val decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols()
    decimalFormatSymbols.decimalSeparator = '.'
    decimalFormatSymbols.groupingSeparator = ','

    val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat()
    decimalFormat.decimalFormatSymbols = decimalFormatSymbols
    decimalFormat.groupingSize = 3

    decimalFormat.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    decimalFormat.minimumFractionDigits = 1

    decimalFormat.maximumIntegerDigits = 8
    decimalFormat.maximumIntegerDigits = 8

    val formattedNumber = decimalFormat.format(number.toDoube())

    println(formattedNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
val number = 12038902.9
val pattern = "##,###,###.##"

val formattedNumber = DecimalFormat(pattern).format(number)
```

Comment: It works fine for pattern "##.###.###,##" but I have to use same with dots (vice versa) i.e., "##.###.###,##" so it throws an exception. 
`Multiple decimal separators in pattern "##.###.###,##"`